# Synchronous communication in Apache Camel between Camel Context's

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, apache-servicemix, architectural-patterns

In the last project I was able to use [direct:vm](http://camel.apache.org/direct-vm.html) component, which is in my opinion the best component to resolve my task. Unfortunately now I can't use it because I'm limited to ServiceMix's Camel version, which is 2.6.0-fuse-00-00, so I've found Normalized Message Router ([NMR](http://camel.apache.org/nmr.html)). I've found information that NMR is asynchronous on default, but can be set as a synchronous by parameter synchronous. Is it still good sollution to use it instead of **direct:vm** component? I'm using it with [enrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) component and I didn't found any problems with that.

Answer (score 3):

In an OSGi environment, each bundle is kept fairly separate from the others. The `NMR` component allows a bundle to expose a Camel route as a resource to other bundles in the container using this facility in ServiceMix. The `direct-vm` component wasn't introduced until Camel 2.10, so for your version the `NMR` component is the best fit. It is still considered *lightweight*, but more feature-rich than directly exposing the routes. It's still better than using the `JBI` technology, which should be considered legacy.

Comment: that's right, but what with transactions? I read that NMR is not supporting them even if they are supporting synchronous communication?

Comment: Yes and no... it's hard to explain, so I'll refer to the documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SMX4NMR/6.+Transactions+and+clustering

Comment: There is not so may information on that page. I've found a nice presentation : http://download.progress.com/5331/open/adobe/psc/iona/112608_fuse_transactions_and_clustering/index.htm but you've got right. It's a complex issue.